# Workflows not starting after fresh install

Tags: dynamics-crm

I just installed Dynamics CRM 4.0. It is working nicely except for workflows. They won't start. I turned on tracing and it appears that there is an IO error. The server is setup with IFD and SSL. No issues accessing it internally or externally. Here is the trace:

```
# CRM Tracing Version 2.0
# LocalTime: 2010-06-08 11:34:58.2
# Categories:
# CallStackOn: No
# ComputerName: FOX-CRM1
# CRMVersion: 4.0.7333.2741
# DeploymentType: OnPremise
# ScaleGroup:
# ServerRole: AppServer, AsyncService, DiscoveryService, WebService, ApiServer, HelpServer, DeploymentService

[2010-06-08 11:34:58.2] Process:CrmAsyncService |Organization:821a137e-7191-49a4-86cc-69101e2b6d20 |Thread:   24 |Category: Platform.Async |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error | AsyncOperationCommand.Execute
>Exception while trying to execute AsyncOperationId: {DF68F483-2C73-DF11-9A34-18A9053B7B38} AsyncOperationType: 1 - System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.CrmService.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSetBase columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.SdkTypeProxyCrmServiceWrapper.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSetBase columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.SdkPluginDescriptionProvider.GetPluginTypeDescription(Guid pluginTypeId, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.PluginTypeCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCache`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.PluginTypeCache.LookupEntry(Guid pluginTypeId, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncOperationCommand.GetPluginType(Guid pluginTypeId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.EventOperation.InternalExecute(AsyncEvent asyncEvent)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncOperationCommand.Execute(AsyncEvent asyncEvent)
```

The only thing I've tried to to update the AsyncSdkRootDomain row in the Deployment table to match the ADSdkRootDomain and the ADApplicationRootDomain values. It was blank. That didn't appear to work.

After some more research, I think this might be caused because the Asynch service can't access the SDK web services using SSL. If this is correct, how would one configure a CRM server for secure access, internal and external (IFD) and still allow asynch service to hit web site?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this figured out...mostly. This was related to the CRM site being secured via SSL, for both internal users and external (via IFD).

The solution is not ideal, but its close. The web site is setup with a certificate, but it allows non-secure connections. Using the IFD deployment tool, both internal and external access uses HTTPS.  We have a DNS entry for the internal access, so it matches the certificate (we don't use the machine name).  The AsynchSdkRootDomain is blank (in DeploymentProperties database).  This indicates that it should use the loop back IP (127.0.0.1).  The registry entry, ServerURL is set to the machine name + port as the path (http://machine-name:80/MSCRMServices). And the LocalSdkPort is set to 443.  This doesn't really make sense, but it's working.